# How to replace a sub-expression when it implicitly exists in an expression

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

In order to make my question clear, I would like to use a simple expression as an toy example.

Suppose we have an expression, which is,

```
f = a + 2*b + c
```

Now I want to replace sub-expression `(a+b)` with `term1`, and `(b+c)` with `term2`, so that I can obtain the result like

```
f = term1 + term2
```

However, I tried functions `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` in Mathematica and the results are

```
[in] f = Replace[f, {(a + b) -> term1, (b + c) -> term2}]
[out] f = a + 2b + c
[in] f = ReplaceAll[f, {(a + b) -> term1, (b + c) -> term2}]
[out] f = a +2b + c
```

which does not make any changes.

So I was wondering if choose the wrong functions? Or there are some other tricks can be used to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Simplify` has an optional second argument which instructs `Simplify` to consider this additional information during the simplification process. This can help when the replacement you want is simpler than what you have.

```
f = a + 2*b + c;
Simplify[f,{a+b==term1,b+c==term2}]
```

instantly gives you

```
term1+term2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
f = a + 2*b + c;
f /. {a -> term1 - b, c -> term2 - b}

(* term1 + term2 *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: This way is tricky but useful!